# Which type of deviation from Rault's law is shown by mixture of water and acetone?

Tags: solutions

There are dispersion forces in acetone amd hydrogen bond in water so what they should show negative deviation but just want it to be confirmed

Comment: Hydrogen bond will be formed between acetone and water.

Answer (score 2):

Water and acetone form a polar/non-polar mix and due to strong bonds, the mix is less volatile than would be predicted by the Ideal Version of Rault's Law (which is a linear parametric weighing of the respective partial vapor pressures).

This results in what is referred to as a negative deviation (as the curve is beneath the straight line associated with the Ideal Version of Rault's Law).

Here is a [good educational video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nich_rwo4hQ) on the topic.